# Synthesize in AppDelegate: NSManagedObjectContext

Tags: ios, nsmanagedobjectcontext, appdelegate

I've been following some examples online for using NSManagedObjectContext. It seems that while none of the examples manually initialize the instance of NSManagedObjectContext in the didFinishLoadingWithOptions method in AppDelegate, you must set _managedObjectContext to self.managedObjectContext. This doesn't seem necessary in other classes, such as controllers?

```
@synthesize managedObjectContext = _managedObjectContext;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    if (_managedObjectContext == 0) {
        // This is the output shown in the log.
        NSLog(@"Not set.");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"It's set!");
    }

    if (self.managedObjectContext == 0) {
        NSLog(@"Not set.");
    } else {
        // This is the output shown in the log.
        NSLog(@"It's set!");
    }

    // Should this line be necessary?
    _managedObjectContext = [self managedObjectContext];

    _navigationController = (UINavigationController*)self.window.rootViewController;
    _chordViewController = (ChordViewController*) _navigationController.topViewController;
    [_chordViewController setManagedObjectContext: _managedObjectContext];
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That line shouldn't be necessary at all.

You've basically set the managedObjectContext variable to itself. It won't technically harm anything, but it isn't helpful either.

In your app delegate file you should have a bunch of boiler plate code to create and manage the context. If you don't, it's likely because you didn't select the "Use Core Data" option when creating the project. When you are creating a new project to use core data, make sure you check that box. It will ensure that the proper code to create the managed object context is inserted in your app delegate file.

EDIT: Ensure that you have this code in your app delegate:

```
// Returns the managed object context for the application.
// If the context doesn't already exist, it is created and bound to the persistent store coordinator for the application.
- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext
{
    if (_managedObjectContext != nil) {
        return _managedObjectContext;
    }

    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
    if (coordinator != nil) {
        _managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
        [_managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];
    }
    return _managedObjectContext;
}
```

If that code is there, you should be all set. Core data is a tricky subject to get a handle on, but it should be working properly with that boiler plate code. You should ALWAYS call self.managedObjectContext to ensure that this method is called. Do not try to access _managedObjectContext directly. That will circumvent the code that properly initializes the MOC in the first place.

Comment: In my controller (which gets passed an instance of NSManagedObject from AppDelegate) I have the following:
```- (void)viewDidLoad { [super viewDidLoad]; if(_managedObjectContext == 0) { NSLog(@"Not set."); } else { NSLog(@"It's set!"); }}``` - when I don't have that line NSLog reports that the pointer is addressed to 0. Why would my AppDelegate not be automatically setting the NSManagedObject context?

Comment: I just created a fresh test project with Core Data selected in Xcode and it seems that the instance is not being automatically created in AppDelegate.m.

Comment: Your managedObjectContext should definitely be created by your app delegate. I just created a new project to confirm. Do you have a custom init method for your controller that passes in the managedObjectContext? The managedObjectContext isn't created until it's needed typically, which would be the first time you use it. That's probably why NSLog would show a 0 pointer for your MOC. That's expected behavior.

Comment: If you look back at the code in my question, it seems that app delegate will automatically instantiate self.managedObjectContext but it won't automatically assign that memory address to the synthesized _managedObjectContext. Do you know why this would be?

Comment: Just to add, the ```@synthesize managedObjectContext = _managedObjectContext;``` was added as boilerplate by Xcode.

Comment: It seems that for the AppDelegate class to set _managedObjectContext, you must first use self.managedObjectContext.

Comment: Yes, exactly. See my edit above. You should always pass self.managedObjectContext to other methods, never the instance variable _managedObjectContext.

Comment: When you use _managedObjectContext you are accessing the variable directly and telling the program "I want this variable: _managedObjectContext no matter what it contains. I don't even care if it hasn't been created yet, just give it to me!" If you use self.managedObjectContext you are telling the program "I want a properly setup MOC. If it's not setup, then do that first and give me the resulting object". Make sense?